Relation between decreased edge weights and increased edge weights by 1
Been trying to solve the following question and I got to some ideas but not a formal proof:
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed strongly connected graph. Let $w$ be a weight function on the edges such that $w(e) > 1$ for every edge $e ∈ E$. For two distinct vertices $s, t ∈ V$, let $d(s, t)$ be the weight of a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ in $G$.
Let $G_1$ be a graph produced from $G$ by increasing by one all the weights. That is, for every $e ∈ E$, $w_1(e) = w(e) + 1$. Let $d(s, t) + Δ_1$ be the weight of a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ in $G_1$.
Let $G_2$ be a graph produced from $G$ by decreasing by one all the weights. That is, for every $e ∈ E$, $w_2(e) = w(e) - 1$. Let $d(s, t) - Δ_2$ be the weight of a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ in $G_2$.
Either determine and fill in the most suitable sign among $\{ ≤, =, ≥ \}$ in the relation $Δ_1$ [ ] $Δ_2$, and prove it, or explain why no sign fits in, that is, present two instances with contradicting relation between $Δ_1$ and $Δ_2$.
From trying out different graphs, it seems like $Δ_2 ≥ Δ_1$ (since the shortest path can change and have either more or less edges once the weights change), but again, I have not found a way to prove it

Why in bold?

To separate the question itself from my comments on it

There are two approaches here. We can just prove an inequality between $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$, but there is an underlying reason for that inequality, and it is the concavity of the optimal value of any linear minimization problem.
Specific solution
Suppose that the shortest $s-t$ path in $G$ has $\ell$ edges. Then its cost in $G_1$ is $d(s,t) + \ell$ and its cost in $G_2$ is $d(s,t) - \ell$. Now, there's no guarantee that this is still the shortest $s-t$ path in either $G_1$ or $G_2$, but the best paths in those graphs are at least as good as this one, so we get the inequalities
\begin{align}
   d(s,t) + \Delta_1 &\le d(s,t) + \ell, \\
   d(s,t) - \Delta_2 &\le d(s,t) - \ell.
\end{align}
Adding these together and simplifying tells us that $\Delta_1 \le \Delta_2$.
Solution via concavity
Generalizing, let $G(x)$ be the weighted graph in which edge $e$ has weight $w(e)+x$, so that $G_1 = G(1)$ and $G_2 = G(-1)$. Let $f(x)$ be the weight of a shortest $s-t$ path in $G(x)$. Then the underlying fact that makes everything work is that $f(x)$ is a concave function.
Here's why. If an $s-t$ path $P$ has length $\ell(P)$ and weight $w(P)$ in $G$, then it has weight $w(P) + x \cdot \ell(P)$ in $G(x)$. By definition, $f(x)$ is the minimum weight over all $s-t$ paths in $G(x)$: that is, $$f(x) = \min_P (w(P) + x \cdot \ell(P)).$$ Each weight $w(P) + x \cdot \ell(P)$ is linear in $x$, and therefore concave (and also convex). The minimum of concave functions is also concave.
For a concave function, we have $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \ge \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}$. In particular, in our case, we have $f(0) \ge \frac{f(-1) + f(1)}{2}$. Substituting the values we are given in the problem statement, we get $$d(s,t) \ge \frac{(d(s,t) - \Delta_2) + (d(s,t) + \Delta_1)}{2}$$ which simplifies, once again, to $\Delta_1 \le \Delta_2$.
More is true. We would get the same behavior if we made any linear change to the weights. That is, if we give every edge $e$ its own constant $c_e$ and set the weight of $e$ to $w(e) + x \cdot c_e$ in $G(x)$ (which would mean increasing the weight by $c_e$ in $G_1$ and decreasing the weight by $c_e$ in $G_2$) then the same result would hold.
We can also see that the shortest-path structure of the problem is basically irrelevant. All that matters is that we have a bunch of candidate solutions (the different $s-t$ paths) whose objective value changes linearly as we change some parameter $x$. For any minimization problem with this property, $f(x)$ will be a concave function of $x$; for a maximization problem, $f(x)$ will be a convex function of $x$.

Thank you for the elaborate answer!
